# Multiple NavigationStack in Xamarin.Forms App with Prism Library

Tags: c#, xamarin, prism

There's some way to create two navigation stacks in Xamarin.Forms App using Prism Library?

I faced this needs to manage two stacks one for the app and another for authentication as shown in the attached image.

Think in scenario when the authentication method of the user has expired(token, session and so on). With another stack it's possible to manage the authentication and afterwards return to exact place before.

[image: tow navagation stacks]
<sub>(source: [xamarinhelp.com](https://xamarinhelp.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/PageFlow-300x283.png))</sub>

Comment: I don't think you need two navigation stacks for this all it needs is logical conditioning

Comment: could you give more detail about this "logical conditioning" ?

Comment: `Think in scenario when the authentication method of the user has expired(token, session and so on).`- When this happens load the page accordingly, your question is your literal answer my friend